# Struct passed to thread (unix) has wrong values

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, struct, pthreads

I'm writing a piece of code based on concurrency in C (under Unix) but seems there are some problems at the very base.

I have a global struct like this:

```
struct i_arg {
    int k;
    int j;
};
```

At run-time, I take a max number `N` and I allocate an array of `struct i_arg` with size `N-1`

```
struct i_arg *t_arg;
...
t_arg = (struct i_arg *) malloc((n-1) * sizeof(struct i_arg));
for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    t_arg[i].k = i;
    t_arg[i].j = i+1;
}
...
```

Given `N`, I also create `N-1`threads and I pass a pointer of `t_arg[i]`to each one

```
for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    retcode = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, swap, (void *) &t_arg[i]);
    if (retcode != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Creation of thread %d failed.\n", i);
}
```

and the `swap`function performs a cast to `(struct i_arg)` immediately:

```
void *swap(void *arg) {

    struct i_arg *ind;
    int i,j;
    ind = (struct i_arg *) arg;
    i = ind->k;
    j = ind->j;

    fprintf(stdout,"Thread %d working... with i= %d, i+1=%d\n", i, i, j);

    ...
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Now the problem:

When `N` is even, the first thread created (thread 0) should receive `arg` with `k=0` and `j=1`. Actually it receives `j=1` but k goes from 0 to a random number.
The `fprintf` will print

```
Thread 4747264 working... with i= 4747264, i+1=1
```

If `N` is odd, the first thread works smoothly and the output, correctly, will be

```
Thread 0 working... with i= 0, i+1=1
```

I tried to `usleep` the main thread after each `pthread_create()`. The result is that if I let it sleep at least 60 microsec, the issue is solved...but how can I avoid `usleep` without having a wrong value?

Comment: Your code works fine for me on Mac OS.  I just added `pthread_t tid[n-1]` up top and `pthread_join(tid[i], NULL)` in a loop at the bottom, and it does what you'd expect.  Maybe you have a bug somewhere else?  I suggest enabling all compiler warnings and running your program under valgrind.

Comment: Given that putting the main thread to sleep for long enough 'resolves' the problem, it suggests that some of the code in the main thread after launching the threads is doing damage to the data structures that the threads are trying to use. I agree with [amdn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/521897/amdn) that the problem is not in the code you do show. Please study the guidelines on how to create an MCTRE [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with the code you snipped out in the `swap` function and show as `...`, do you store back into the t_arg array of i_arg structs?

```
for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    t_arg[i].k = i;
    t_arg[i].j = i+1;
}
```

when i==n-2, you will initialize j to n-1, which is one past your array size.  This is how you allocate:

```
t_arg = (struct i_arg *) malloc((n-1) * sizeof(struct i_arg));
```

and this is how you initialize

```
t_arg[i].j = i+1;  /* bug is likely here when i==n-2,  */
```

If you use `t_arg[i].j` as an index into your array it will be undefined when i==n-2 and j==n-1.

My suggestion is to allocate `N` entries and dispatch N-1 threads.  With `N` entries there are only N-1 adjacent things to swap (for N > 0).

```
t_arg = (struct i_arg *) malloc( n * sizeof(struct i_arg) );
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    t_arg[i].k = i;
    t_arg[i].j = i+1;
}
```